# GAE 1.7.3 - How to debug appengine-web.xml XML error validating

Tags: google-app-engine

How do you fix xml validation errors in appengine.web.xml.

First the error message told me to add "true".

And now it just fails, saying that the valiadtion failed - but, what to do?

I did fix this, by creating a new ApEngine project and copied it over, but how do you find the errors?

Looking for the process on finding the errors?

Regards

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `appengine-web.xml` file?

Comment: Hi - I did fix it, by creating a new AppEngine project and copying the appengine.web.xml. But, I am looking for the process on how to find the errors. I will changed the text, to be more clear. Thanks